# Interface library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to make interface function in my library.
i dont know why its not running.
please help me.

this is my controlller :

```
$status_id = 1;
$parameter_strategy = array($user_id, $post, $vehicle_class_id, $coverage_package_id, $vehicle_relationship_id, $zone_id, $order_type, $status_id);
$strategy = $this->load->library ( "ApiSync/SyncStrategy", $parameter_strategy) ;
```

this is my library :

```
    <?php
    require ( "StrategyMV.php" ) ;
    class SyncStrategy 
    {
        private $strategy = NULL;
        public function __construct ( $parameter_strategy )
        {
            $user_id = $params[0];
            $post = $params[1];
            $vehicle_class_id = $params[2];
            $coverage_package_id = $params[3];
            $vehicle_relationship_id = $params[4];
            $zone_id = $params[5];
            $order_type = $params[6];
            $status_id = $params[7];

            switch ( $cart_type )
            {
                case "MV" : $this->strategy = new StrategyMV();
                break;
                case "TV":
                break;
                case "PAR":
                break;
            }
        }
public function insert_cart ( $user_id, $post )
    {
        $result['message'] = 'Success Insert Cart';
        return $this->strategy->insert_cart( $user_id, $post );
    }
}

interface SyncInterface
{
    public function insert_cart ( $user_id, $post  ) ;
}
```

this is my StrategyMV.php file

```
<?php

class StrategyMV implements SyncInterface
{

    public function insert_cart ( $user_id, $post )
    {
        $this->load->model('synchdb');
        $insurance_id = 0;
        $datacart = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'order_id' => 0,
            'is_recycled' => 0,
            'is_finish' => 0,
            'request_constructed' => 0, //test for 0 value 1st
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'type_tvmv' => ($post['cart_type'] == 'TV') ? '0': '1',
            'selected_insurance_id' => $insurance_id,
            'stamp_duty' => 0,//$post['cart_stamp_duty'],
            'policy_cost' => 0,//$post['cart_policy_cost'],
            'handling_fee' => 0,//$post['cart_handling_fee'],
            'discount' => 0,//$post['cart_discount'],
            'mark_cost' => 0,//$post['cart_mark_cost'],
            'brokerage_cost' => 0//$post['cart_brokerage_cost']
        );

        return $cart_id = $this->synchdb->insertCart($datacart);
    }
}
```

the problem is my library is not running.
i dont know how to fix it.
please help me.
many thanks in return.

Comment: Have look here how to name files for CI http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: You may need to use get_instance in the CI library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=get%20instance#get_instance

Comment: i already put $CI =& get_instance(); still not working brother

Comment: I don't see `$cart_type` is defined anywhere before switch statement. Also put your interface code before  `require( "StrategyMV.php" )` line.